# Custom attribute value is not getting saved in Address Book?

Tags: magento2

I have created `address_nationality` attribute using script

```
$customerSetup -> addAttribute('customer_address',
        'address_nationality',
        [
        'label' => 'Nationality',
        'system' => 0,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'position' => 110,
        'sort_order' =>110,
        'visible' =>  true,
        'default_value' => '',
        'note' => '',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',
        ]
        );
    $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer_address', 'address_nationality')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('default_value','')-> setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address', 'customer_address_edit']) -> save();
```

In address book I am trying to save value of `address_nationality` but it is not getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking you need to add the attribute to the `customer_form_attribute` as well:

```
$customAttribute->setData(
    'used_in_forms',
    ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
);
$customAttribute->save();
```

I'm guessing that you can use the `used_in_forms`-parameter in the creation of the attribute as well.

Comment: I have already added. It is there in customer_form_attribute table